# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in mainPage.php on line 109

Tags: php

this is my code below.

```
<h2 align=center><strong>Fan Pages</strong></h2>
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); 
$query = "SELECT pageName FROM pages";
//loop through the results and display them
   while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc())
   {
'<a href = "viewFanPage.php?id=<?php echo '.$row['page_ID']'; ?>"><?php echo '.$row['pageName']'; ?></a>';
   }
```

?>

I want the name field  to be echoed as a link but I keep getting this error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in \mainPage.php on line 109.

I have tried everything but still no headway, will appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Inside the while loop you didn't leave php mode, but it looks like you wanted to?

Comment: `'.$row['page_ID']';` <-- you aren't concatenating properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoted strings aren’t sent to output automatically and don’t interpret `<?php … ?>` pseudo-tags. It looks like you meant to close and reopen the `<?php … ?>` instead:

```
<h2 align="center"><strong>Fan Pages</strong></h2>

<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); 

$query = "SELECT pageName FROM pages";

// loop through the results and display them
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
    <a href="viewFanPage.php?id=<?php echo $row['page_ID']; ?>">
        <?php echo $row['pageName']; ?>
    </a>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. It worked perfectly.